# svn log differing results (-r)

Tags: svn

I've been reading the svn documentation and can't find anything regarding this.

But, I've been working on an svn system where when I try

```
svn log -r 168
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    r168 | dsaadsads | 2010-16-21 13:14:47 -0700 (Wed, 232 Jun 2321313) | 9 lines

    .....
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but when I do

```
svn log | grep "r168"
```

I get no results. Why is this the case? I thought svn log would return all entries unless a limit was specified?

Comment: Try running `svn log | less` and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the revision affect the working copy you work with?

Check [`svn log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) command-line reference.

1. > If no arguments are supplied, svn log shows the log messages for all
   >   files and directories inside (and including) the current working
   >   directory of your working copy. You can refine the results by
   >   specifying a path, one or more revisions, or any combination of the
   >   two. The default revision range for a local path is BASE:1.
2. > If you specify a URL alone, it prints log messages for everything the
   >   URL contains. If you add paths past the URL, only messages for those
   >   paths under that URL will be printed. The default revision range for a
   >   URL is HEAD:1.